# SQL Developer - GIT

Tags: sql, git, oracle, gitlab, oracle-sqldeveloper

I'm trying to use a repository GIT to do version control of packages. Everything is working right now but when I try to create new packages it's grayed out. Any help guys? Thank you guys. 
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Do you have a database connection available?

If not, choose 'Database Files' instead. That will just give you a .SQL file in an editor you can work with w/o a database connection.

Comment: @thatjeffssmith I do have a database connection, but is separated from the repository. If I put the database in the repository would the options be available? I'm trying to set up a way to do version control of packages. Thank you.

Comment: the 'new package' dialog you're attempting to navigate to is not connected to the Git client

Comment: connect to your database, then right-click on the package node, and try 'New Package'

Comment: Thanks. Quick question, I closed the Git window with the files and now I don't know how to open it.

Comment: View > Files or Team > Versions

Comment: brand new content on YouTube on SQLDev and GIT https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=2-x_MyzvI_k&feature=youtu.be